# We're given the function $f(x) = x^2 + bx + c \quad(b,c \in R)$. Value of the function $f(0)$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Given the function $$
>   f(x) = x^2 + bx + c \quad(b,c \in R)
> $$ 
>   such that $f(f(1)) = f(f(2)) = 0$ and $f(1) \neq f(2)$,
>   what is the value of $f(0)$?

Have no basic clue how to do this.

Comment: $f(0)$ is not a function - it's a constant.

Answer (score 9):

$f(1),f(2)$ are the two different roots of $f(x)=x^2+bx+c$, so by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas): $$f(1)+f(2)=-b, \ \ \ f(1)f(2)=c$$

This gives you a system of two equations with two variables ($b,c$).

$$f(1)+f(2)=(1+b+c)+(4+2b+c)=-b$$

$$\iff b=\frac{-2c-5}{4}$$

Substitute this into

$$f(1)f(2)=(1+b+c)(4+2b+c)=c$$

and solve a quadratic equation in $c=f(0)$.